# Selecting from database with a sequence of three

Tags: mysql, sql, math

I want to group ids in my table in three groups and every day to select one of that group and repeat the cycle every 4th day. I don't know if I explained correctly but I will try to do it on an example. Let's say we have ids `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10...n` 
The first day I want to select `1,4,7,10...n` the second day `2,5,8,11...n` and the third day `3,6,9,12...n`. This was very easy when I was doing pretty much the same with odd and even ids. On odd days I was selecting odd ids and on even days even ids. But now I need to do it with 3 day period. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Define 'first day'. And is the 'second day' the day after the 'first day'?

Comment: @Strawberry: I'm confused.  Surely this question similarly violates the community guidelines for failing to include a "minimal, complete, and verifiable example"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the MOD(x,y) function which returns the remainder of x divided by y and the function TO_DAYS(some_date_here) which returns the number of days since year 0. By using the function NOW() inside TO_DAYS we get a new number every day. Put that in modulus also, and this will generate a cycle every 3 days that will select ids like

1,4,7,10...

the next day

2,5,8,11...

the next day

3,6,9,12

and the next day back from the top again

So this query will work without modification every day:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE MOD(my_id,3)=MOD(TO_DAYS(NOW()),3)
```

This grouping can change easily, just change the "3" to whatever you want (be carefull you ll need to change the "3" in **BOTH** `MOD()`s )

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE
id%3 = 1 -- for day 1
id%3 = 2 -- for day 2
id%3 = 0 -- for day 3
```

Or you can use:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE CASE WHEN id % 3 = 0 THEN 3
                   ELSE id % 3
              END = YourDayNumber
```

Sample:

```
SELECT id,
'Day ' + CAST(CASE WHEN id % 3 = 0 THEN 3
                   ELSE id % 3
              END AS VARCHAR(100)) DayNbr
FROM 
(
SELECT 1 id
UNION
SELECT 2
UNION
SELECT 3
UNION
SELECT 4
UNION
SELECT 5
UNION
SELECT 6
UNION
SELECT 7
UNION
SELECT 8
UNION
SELECT 9
) a
```

Comment: he asked for 3 groups. Why to do life complicated?

Comment: And what will be the scalable solution?

Comment: @sidux you already did life complicated. see my one liner answer xD

Comment: modified the answer and made it scalable

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT * FROM ints;
    +---+
    | i |
    +---+
    | 0 |
    | 1 |
    | 2 |
    | 3 |
    | 4 |
    | 5 |
    | 6 |
    | 7 |
    | 8 |
    | 9 |
    +---+

    SELECT * FROM ints WHERE MOD(i,3) = MOD(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),'2015-03-20'),3);
    +---+
    | i |
    +---+
    | 1 |
    | 4 |
    | 7 |
    +---+

    SELECT * FROM ints WHERE MOD(i,3) = MOD(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),'2015-03-21'),3);
    +---+
    | i |
    +---+
    | 0 |
    | 3 |
    | 6 |
    | 9 |
    +---+

    SELECT * FROM ints WHERE MOD(i,3) = MOD(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),'2015-03-22'),3);
    +---+
    | i |
    +---+
    | 2 |
    | 5 |
    | 8 |
    +---+

    SELECT * FROM ints WHERE MOD(i,3) = MOD(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),'2015-03-23'),3);
    +---+
    | i |
    +---+
    | 1 |
    | 4 |
    | 7 |
    +---+

Obviously, add 1 to the calculation if necessary.
```